# A function into another function jquery

Tags: jquery, function

My question is maybe simple but I can't find the answer over the internet so i'm asking here :

I have the following code :

```
function TriggerHeader() {
//doing great stuff
}
function TriggerSlider() {
//doing other stuff
}
```

After every conditions have been examinated, I have a function that calls the right triggers.

```
function Action() {
    $(".content").fadeOut("fast",function () {
    TriggerSlider() {
        TriggerHeader();
    };
});
}
```

So the TriggerSlider() is called when the (".content").fadeOut is over (as I want it to be)
but I'm looking for the correct way to call TriggerHeader(); when the TriggerSlider() is over. The way I wrote it is wrong, but I don't know why. 
Can somebody enlight me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the contents of `TriggerSlider` and `TriggerHeader`.

### If they are synchronous:

```
TriggerSlider();
TriggerHeader();
```

### If `TriggerSlider` has a single animation with a callback available:

```
function TriggerSlider(callb) {
   //Most of your code here
   $("element").slideUp(callb);
}
TriggerSlider(TriggerHeader);
```

### Using the Promise API

```
function TriggerSlider() {
   //Most of your code here
   return $("element").slideUp();
}
$.when(TriggerSlider()).done(TriggerHeader);
```

Comment: It works fine with the Promise API (doesn't work with the callback)
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

These lines are syntactically incorrect:

```
TriggerSlider() {
    TriggerHeader();
};
```

You'd have to adapt the `TriggerSlider` function to allow for a callback, once it is finished:

```
function TriggerSlider(callback) {
    // do stuff
    // ... 
    // now invoke the callback: 
    callback();
    // or pass it to a jQuery function
}
```

Now you can set up the chain like this:

```
function Action() {
    $(".content").fadeOut("fast",function () {
        TriggerSlider(TriggerHeader);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how `TriggerSlider()` and `TriggerHeader()` are implemented. If they don't do anything involving timeouts and 'separate threads', they way to call one after the other would be:

```
TriggerSlider();
TriggerHeader();
```

;-)

On the other hand, if `TriggerSlider()` contains animations or other things that are asynchronous, you'll need to implement it's completion callback as a parameter to the function:

```
function TriggerSlider(completionCallback) {
  setTimeout(500, function() {
    // do something
    // and finally
    completionCallback();
  }
}
```

Now you can call your TriggerSlider and pass it the function to call on completions:

```
TriggerSlider(TriggerHeader);
```

Note that I don't pass `TriggerHeader()`, because that would *call the function and return the result*. I pass the function as a function, and the function call occurs in `TriggerSlider`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are trying to redefine what Triggerslider does when you are writing it the way that you did `TriggerSlider() { //code }`. This is not syntactically correct.

If you want to execute the header function after the slider this should work.

```
function TriggerHeader() {
  //doing great stuff
}

function TriggerSlider() {
  //doing other stuff
  TriggerHeader();
}
function Action() {
   $(".content").fadeOut("fast",function () { TriggerSlider();});
}
```

There are other ways to go at this problem using callbacks. but if you always want to trigger the same functions in order this should work.